# VBA: Combine two cells to form a series name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to combine two text pieces in two different cells to form the name of a series. There should be a blank space between both pieces. Unfortunately, I get a

> runtime error 1004

```
Dim Dataws As Worksheet
Dim Chtws As Worksheet

Set Dataws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
Set Chtws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart")

Set ChtObj = Chtws.ChartObjects("ChartA")

With Dataws
    CurrentRow = 13
    Do Until Range("A" & CurrentRow) = ""
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Loop
End With

With ChtObj
Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With Ser
        .Name = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) & " " & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 5).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .Values = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 6).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Have you declared  ChtObj ?

Comment: As Luuklag said, your current code is using the cell address not the cell text

Comment: As an aside, how have you declared ChtObj?

Comment: Thanks, it was because of the "=" at the start. That was causing the error. And yes, I declared ChtObj.

Comment: @Fiops, I summarized it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Name = Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Text & " " & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Text` would be the formula you need.

Your `.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)` will return you the external cell reference. As you state you want to combine the text from both cells you should use `.Text`

As your formula now does not evaluate to something usefull, the `=` you had at the beginning should be removed.